# ERLANG - wxGrid register

Tags: erlang, grid, parallel-processing, wxwidgets

Im having some trouble with the erlang wx module.

My program runs as follows:

```
Server = wx:new(),
Frame = wxFrame:new(Server, -1, "" [{size,{700, 600}}]),  %%%REFERENCE TO WINDOW
Panel  = wxPanel:new(Frame),  %%% REF TO PANEL IN FRAME
```

Then I pass Panel to another process and try to create a Grid

```
XreportZ  = wxGrid:new(Panel, 24, [ {pos, {0,0}} , {style, 1}] ),
```

The problem occurs when I pass panel, erlang says that the object Panel becomes invalid outside of its local process.  So how is it that I can reference Panel outside of the function that spawned it.  I do not believe register can be used for this.  I belive the answer lies somewhere is referencing the Server and getting back the Panel ID.

To date I still can find no answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did You try "[wx:get_env/0](http://erlang.org/doc/man/wx.html#get_env-0)"?

I am not too deep inside wxErlang/wxWidgets, but maybe this could be a start...

Comment: Although this is correct it is only half the truth. Use get env send the token to the other process and have it set env. That should work. :)

Comment: Sounds like the end of the functional approaches in Erlang :o)